# How to make an ImageButton circular with a rectangular image inside?

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android-imagebutton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProfileMainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="240dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        />


</FrameLayout>
```

[image: AppScreen]

I need the image to be cropped within the black circle , but it doesn't happen.

Moreover I noticed that the ripple from the ImageButton touch goes out in a circular area, so I was guessing that there might be some way to fit the image within that area itself.

Dimension of Stock Image:- 495x495

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you recreate the image as circular bitmap. You can use this a method like this one. Just introduce the necessary round pixels.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    if (bitmap == null)
        return null;

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a library you can easily fixed this issue> This may helps you [com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView). Hope that it works and solve your issue